# Averaging two rows in a dataset, based on them having the same value in another column,

Tags: r

Lets give this another shot. This time i tried including data.

I have a dataset of 108 rows, and 654 columns (pictured is a sample of the 8 initial columns). What i have here is 54 different samples for which i have two readings. I would like to average the absorbance columns [6:653] for each clone (column 2) (the clones are formatted like '11-45-N'). There is a reading A, and a reading B. These need to be averaged, then placed into a new table, and this new table must preserve the data in columns 1, 2, 3, and 654 (these cells are the for both readings, but are not necessarily numeric, as you can see). For example, the first 3 columns in the first line for the new table should read exactly the same as the first line for the sample below, but not include the 'reading and ID' columns. Please note, the removal of those two columns is purely a quality of life thing, my main ask it getting the averages, and retaining the info in the other columns.

I have attempted using `plyr` and `rollapply` functions, but I am still relatively new to this, and cannot really figure it out.

```
     Reslevel   clone bagnumber reading ID absorbence.8987.71322 absorbence.8979.99845 absorbence.8972.28367
1           H 11-45-N        16     A.0  1              -1.40435              -1.40512              -1.40558
649         H 11-45-N        16     B.0  2              -1.45466              -1.45544              -1.45590
1297        H  8-23-N        11     A.0  3              -1.42534              -1.42613              -1.42665
1945        H  8-23-N        11     B.0  4              -1.45738              -1.45803              -1.45853
2593        H  8-29-N        11     A.0  5              -1.46860              -1.46937              -1.46987
3241        H  8-29-N        11     B.0  6              -1.44404              -1.44487              -1.44543
```

Comment: You can use `rowMeans` for that

Comment: Do you want the average across columns or across rows? Or both? I'm confused now :-)

Comment: I would like to an average for each column. I.e. for clone "11-45-N", it would average -1.40435 and -1.45466 for the "absorbence.8987.71322" column, and so on for then next 648 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
aggregate(. ~ Reslevel + clone + bagnumber + last_col_name, data=dataset_name, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Dude, you are a genius, I think this has worked - i'll double check with some random calculations, but from the few i have done, this has worked. 

I love you.